# Restrict File type in File Upload

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, drupal-9

I have created a Webform in Drupal 9 and I am using File Upload Field of type document field. We have added condition in setting to accept only pdf, doc, docx files. However user is able to upload php files using the exploit throught script. However on the server we checked the uploaded php files are getting saved with extension txt.

E.g user uploaded test.php file, it is saved as test.php.txt file on server.

Is there a way to restrict user to upload php files?

Thanks,
Akshay Sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a validation of your form in a custom module.
**Example**:

In your custom.module:

```
 function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
      if ($form_id == 'webform_submission_yourformid_add_form') {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'yourcustommodule_form_validate';     
      }
  }




  public function yourcustommodule_form_validate(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
   
      $extensions= array('doc','docx','pdf');

      $files  = $form_state->getValue('yourfilefield');
      foreach($files["uploaded_files"] as $item => $val){
          $filename=  $val["filename"];
          $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
          if (!in_array($ext, $extensions)) {
            $form_state->setErrorByName('yourfilefield', t('Error') );
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: So does Drupal 9 internally renames the php/js files to .txt when we try to upload them? Is this the expected behavior?